# Visualizing Normal Subgroups

Tags: normal-subgroups, visualization

I'm reading Nathan Carter's "Visual Group Theory" and I'm a little stuck on his choice of words and want to make sure I understand his statement correctly. It concerns normal subgroups and is stated as follows:

" ...at Figure 6.8 on page 104, which helped us picture a left coset *gH* as the copy of *H* to which the *g* arrow from *e* leads. That figure also depicts the right coset *Hg* as the nodes that *g* arrows can reach from *H*. These visualizations tell us that the defining characteristic of normal subgroups, *gH* = *Hg*, can be restated as follows: To whichever coset one *g* arrow leads from 
*H* (the left coset *gH*),
all *g* arrows lead unanimously (because it is also the right coset *Hg*)."

I'm confused about the part "the left coset *gH*" in parentheses. If *gH* is the copy of *H* at the node *g*, what does this have to do with "whichever coset one *g* arrow leads from *H*"?

Comment: You _may_ have found a typo in the book. A quick reading suggests (to me) that the $H$ in your quote (from the parentheses) should perhaps be $e$. Let's see what other people say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a general subgroup H, the left cosets *gH* look like copies of *H* at the node *g* in the Caley diagram (we could say that left multiplication by *g* moves *H* as a block), while right cosets are more scattered, in the sense that different elements of the right coset belong to different left cosets. But when *H* is normal (*gH=Hg*), since every right coset is also a left coset, right multiplication must also move *H* as a block around the Caley diagram, and that is probably the intended meaning of "all *g* arrows lead unanimously".

So I think the intended meaning of the sentence is: The defining characteristic of a normal subgroup is that all *g* arrows from *H* lead to the same left coset, which must be *gH* (since *gH* and *Hg* always share at least one element: *g*)

So: "To whichever coset one *g* arrow leads from *H* (the left coset gH **[NOTE: Because in fact every element of *Hg* must belong to some left coset]**) all g arrows lead unanimously (because it is also the right coset *Hg* **[NOTE: Because *gH=Hg*]**)"

Comment: Ahhh okay this makes perfect sense, thank you so much!!